# How do I put data from my sublist into new dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a large list of lists. I am trying to put each sublist into a dictionary where the key=index0 and the value =index1 of each sublist.
for example
`[['a', '90'], ['b', '30'], ['v', '78'], ['e', '213'], ['y', '6'], ['z', '38']]` etc...(about 100 other values)

The code I've tried is

```
player_1_data_dict = {i:[0]: i[1] for i in player_1_data_dict}
```

returns invalid syntax, but can't figure out what the issue is

The expected output would be
`{'a': '90', 'b': '30', 'v': '78'}` etc.

Comment: remove the extra `:`. this line should be as follows `player_1_data_dict = {i[0]: i[1] for i in player_1_data_dict}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code. The correct statement is:

```
player_1_data_dict = {i[0]: i[1] for i in player_1_data_dict}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call `dict` on your list of list:

```py
list_of_lists = [['a', '90'], ['b', '30'], ['v', '78']]
result = dict(list_of_lists)
# result = {'a': '90', 'b': '30', 'v': '78'}
```

`dict` takes in a sequence of key/values, so this list of list is perfect input.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code, you just need to change your code to:

```
player_1_data_dict = {i[0]: i[1] for i in player_1_data_dict}
```

i[0] returns the first element of each sublist and i[1] returns the second element